# How to combine find with custom tests?

Tags: bash, command-line, find

I am trying to learn the Linux command line, but I am having problems understanding the `find` command.

I would like to list all the directories which contain the directory `.hg`.

This list all the directories:

```
find -type d
```

and this is the test I want to perform:

```
[ -d .hg ]
```

According to the **find man page:**

```
find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]
```

where expression contains tests. But this:

```
find -type d [ -d .hg ]
```

doesn't work.

What is the correct syntax here? I am sorry that this is such an elementary question, but I have absolutely nobody to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could make it:

```
find . -type d  -exec test -e "{}/.hg" ';' -print
```

So it looks for directories and in each one of them it check the existence of the dir `.hg`. It just prints the ones that return true.

You can find [many examples in ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/196960/143251).

#### Test

```
$ mkdir t1
$ mkdir -p t2/.hg
$ mkdir -p t3/t4/.hg
$ find . -type d  -exec test -e "{}/.hg" ';' -print
./t2
./t3/t4
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say that it's better to simply find the .hg directories, and just remove them from output. Like:

```
find . -type d -name .hg | sed 's#/.hg$##'
```

The reason is very simple - `find .. -exec` will launch a subshell for every directory. On the other hand - my solution will just find the .hg files using normal directory traversal, and then will remove obsolete .hg at the end using text processing tool.

Comment: This also works. Also thank you for the insight on the subshell!

Answer (score 2):

A 100% pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) solution:

```
shopt -s globstar
for i in **/.hg/; do
    echo "${i%/.hg/}"
done
```

or if you don't mind seeing all the trailing `/.hg/`:

```
shopt -s globstar; printf "%s\n" **/.hg/
```